# Dynamicly positioned popup in react native flatlist

Tags: react-native

I have a react app with a group of components. I have a group of cards and a popup. What I want is, that whenever a user clicks on a card it should show the popup.
My current structure is:

```
<CardWrapper>
   <Popup></Popup>
   <Card>...</Card>
   <Card>...</Card>
   <Card>...</Card>
</CardWrapper>
```

Right now the `CardWrapper` position is relative and the `Popup` position is absolute. And whenever a user clicks on a card it will show the `Popup`.
But, right now the position to display the `Popup` is relative to `Cardwrapper`.
no matter where the user clicks the `Popup` will always be displayed as

[image]

But, I want it to be relative to the card clicked on. like:

if the user clicks on card 2

[image]

or if the user clicks on card 4

[image]

I don't know how to achieve that. My popup should not be inside my cards. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: ahh nice question, will think how to achieve this

Comment: Not with css, absolute positioning needs the parent to be `position: relative` to use `top: 0` on the child. Unless you know the height of all the cards can add them all together which is hacky.

can you pass the popup as a prop?

Comment: @PetrolHead yes I can pass it as a prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh , finally thanks to your question , i learned so many things. ive finally achieved what exactly your question is

THis is the working solution [Expo link](https://snack.expo.dev/hPw1ddWmf)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet ,FlatList ,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import {useRef , createRef , useState} from 'react'


export default function App() {

  const data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

  const [topH,setTop] = useState(0)

  const elementsRef = useRef(data.map(() => createRef()));

  const onCardPress = (item,newRef) => {

 newRef?.current?.measureInWindow( (fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
            console.log('Component width is: ' + width)
            console.log('Component height is: ' + height)
            console.log('X offset to frame: ' + fx)
            console.log('Y offset to frame: ' + fy)
            console.log('X offset to page: ' + px)
            console.log('Y offset to page: ' + py)

            setTop(fy)
        })        
  }

const renderEach = ({item,index}) => {


  return(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onCardPress (item,elementsRef?.current[index])} style={styles.eachCard} ref={elementsRef?.current[index]} >
    <Text>{item}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

const Popup = () => {
  if(topH === 0 ){
    return null
  }
  return(
    <View style={{backgroundColor:'yellow' , position:'absolute',zIndex:3 , height:60,width:60 , right:30 , top:topH}} >
    <Text> popup </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{flex:1}} >
      <Popup />
      <FlatList 
      style={{flex:1}}
      data={data}
      renderItem={renderEach}
       />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  eachCard:{
    height:100,
    margin:10,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor:'#850D5F'
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

so here basically if you see we have dynamic refs and also `newRef?.current?.measureInWindow` is the one which gives us layout position wrt to Y which is relative to frame, and im setting the same in `top` position

Please feel free for doubts. also see the results of what ive achieved. hope its your doubt

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution works if my cards are fixed height cards. But, mine is expandable cards.

Comment: still it doesnt matter, even if its dynamic it will work

Comment: it all matters when you click on that card, it will show that popup where it is

Comment: @WahidullahShadab if the answer helped do mark as accepted and upvote :) motivates me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need a component to be in the parent but rendered in the child you can pass it as a prop,

ie

```
const popup = () => {
  return <Popup/>
}

const Parent = () => {
return (
  <CardWrapper>
   <Card popup={popup}>...</Card>
   <Card popup={popup}>...</Card>
   <Card popup={popup}>...</Card>
  </CardWrapper>
)
```

Then the Card can render the popup and position is absolutely relative to itself

Comment: Is there any way I can render the popup on the card wrapper and position it based on the card?
I am using a library for these cards which are expandable cards.  and when it's expanded the popup will go beneath the expanded part of the card. 
I already tried `z-index` for my pop-up but it's not working.

Comment: Not without getting the Card to render the popup. With position, fixed, sticky, or absolute you need the parent to be `position: relative`.

The card library should allow you to pass children in but you will have to write it like this `<Card>{popup()}</Card>` but I'm not sure if it will allow you to set the style to `position: relative;`